# How to switch from Kubuntu to Lubuntu

Tags: installation, kubuntu, lubuntu

How can someone switch from Kubuntu to Ubuntu? 
I need the OS to be more lighter than Kubuntu, so I need things to be unistalled from Kubuntu and the LXDE to be installed.

I am talking about 11.10 .

EDIT: I care alot if my system will be lightweight!

This PC is very old.(512 MB RAM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be better to do those operations from a TTY not from a terminal, do CTRL+ALT+F1 and logon on a real TTY.

1. Optionnal : Uninstall Kubuntu desktop `sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop` -> It's optionnal because you can have both environements installed but only one running.
2. Then remove it dependencies `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`
3. After that, install the lubuntu desktop `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
4. Then, `reboot` your machine.

Be carefull : this process might corrupt the system, do a backup before proceed.

Comment: after following these steps and reboot, linux boots up in completely black page without any program loaded, just mouse working and no shortcut do anything. now lost my Linux completely

Answer (score 1):

The question is how to get back to Ubuntu from Kubuntu then install LXDE so then:

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelxde

If you were wanting just Ubuntu then : [Getting Back to a Pure Gnome on Ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome)

Comment: Kubuntu to Lubuntu, not Ubuntu? That should be http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelxde